# Why does fetching from local grape Api (rails server) cause repeated GET-Requests and/or page reloads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fetch, get-request, ruby-grape

I set up a minimal grape Api in my example rails application. I generated a Model (rails generate model Example (title:string, count:integer)), added to instances via the rails console and installed Grape 2.0.0.

I added api/root.rb in the app-directory:

```
class Root < Grape::API
    format :json
    
    get '/examples' do
        Example.all
    end

    get '/examples/:id' do
        Example.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I added to config/routes.rb:

```
mount Root => "/api"
```

I modified config/application.rb and added:

```
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'api')

    # Load API endpoints
    config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
```

Checking in the browser "localhost:3000/examples" return the expected JSON-Objects.

In a different directory (not the rails project) I set up a index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Error Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and an app.js-file fetching from localhost:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/examples");
```

When I open index.html with LiveServer (running on 5501) the page reloads constantly and makes repeated GET-requests to the rails server. Sometimes it will eventually stop having loaded the data correctly, sometimes incorrectly. Anyone sees what is wrong here?

I tried to fetch from a different url (eg. 'https://dummyjson.com/products/1'), which worked absolutely fine without the repeated reloads. Hence I suspect the error to be within in rails app, being completely new to rails I could not pin point it though. Any help, hints or wake up calls are appreciated!